# Return by reference a increased variable

Tags: php

I know this is simple example, and know why return 21, but dont understand why its working in this way php:

```
    function increase(&$a) { 
       return $a++; // now i expect $a = 2, but return FIRST the reference (1), an increase later..? 
    }

    $a = 1; 
    $b = increase($a);

    echo $a.$b;
```

Special behavior with operators and byRef?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$a++` is post-incrementation 
the old value of `$a` is returned and not the incremented value.

but in case of `++$a` it is pre-incrementation, the value of `$a` is incremented and the new value is returned.

So, in this case if `$a = 1` and you do `$a++` it will return `1`, while if you use `++$a` it will return `2`.

Comment: Now i understand, i miss this, think ++$x and $x++ its the same, but works 1º return value and late increasing. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When `$a` is initially `1`, the post-increment operator in the function tells PHP To return `1`, and then increment `$a` to `2`.... so the returned value assigned to `$b` is 1; and the by-reference ensures that the incremented `$a` is its new value in the global scope.

You're then concatenating `$a` (now `2` following the post-increment) with `$b` (`1`) giving `21`